# LaTeX, tildes and verbatim mode

Tags: latex

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256457/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex/256620), I'm totally stumped on getting LaTeX to give me a tilde when I'm in verbatim mode.  It has to be a tilde because it's the type of a function!

```
sig symm : (Board, [(Int, Int)]) ~> Bool
```

Standard methods for displaying a tilde are printed verbatim, of course..

Any suggestions?

*An edit to clarify*: Typing a ~ in verbatim mode gives an accent above a blank space.  I'm after a tilde as it appears at the beginning of this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are some characters that do not occur in your input, you can use fancyvrb and its commandchars option to insert TeX commands within verbatim text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytilde}{$\sim$}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
sig symm : (Board, [(Int, Int)]) \mytilde> Bool
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

See the documentation of [fancyvrb](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should look at: [LaTeX package to do syntax highlighting of code in various languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300521/latex-package-to-do-syntax-highlighting-of-code-in-various-languages) which has suggestions for typesetting code...

---

I assumed that [`listing`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) would do it for you, but failing that [`alltt`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=alltt) and [`fancyvrb`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=fancyvrb) are alternatives to `verbatim`. See [this search on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/cgi-bin/search.py?metadataSearch=verbatim&metadataSearchSubmit=Search) for other possibilities.

Comment: That's an awful lot of effort just to get a tilde!  And as far as I can see with experimenting and reading documentation, it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: alltt looked promising but still appears to give the accented tilde.  I'll hunt though the options of both packages, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using listing command, you can set the tilde to be literal. Likt this.

```
\documentclass
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    literate={~} {$\sim$}{1} % set tilde as a literal (no process)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
~
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{verbatim}
~
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: LOL. I just assume that aradnuk had alread tried and failed! +1

Comment: A single tilde places an accent over an invisible letter, if you will, so it's up high rather than in the centre of the line.

Comment: @aradnuk: You should probably edit the question to reflect your desire to have a "full-sized" tilde centered vertically...

Comment: @aradnuk: no, it places tilde in the centre of the line. I tried many combinations and I get always tilde in the center of line.

Comment: maybe this depends on the encoding of the input file? just a guess