# Writing a LaTeX document with Python code snippets

Tags: python, latex

I am using LaTeX to write a document about Python. This document will contain code snippets (examples).

I could use the `verbatim` environment, but before I embark onto it, I'd like to know if you are aware of any LaTeX style file which provides an environment for Python code. Syntax highlight would be a plus.

Thanks.

Edit:

I must point out that the package `minted` is exactly what I was looking for. It has beautiful syntax highlighting and it is very simple to use. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex) to know more about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this question [Source code highlighting in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex) for more information.

You should also look at the [pygments](http://pygments.org/) program for source code highlighting.

I personally use Emacs org-mode with `#+BEGIN_SRC python` and let `htmlize.el` take care of the highlighting during export. You can see a sample [here](http://nibrahim.net.in/self-defence) (This is an HTML export but with the latest version of org-mode, it can use the listings LaTeX package to colourise exported PDFs too).

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry about having repeated the question unknowingly. The package minted is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use Docutils and RST for this.  It has Latex with Syntax highlighting.

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/latex.html

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX Listings package seems to know about Python.  Worth taking a look at.

Mark