# How to run minted package in TeXnicCenter using MiKTeX 

Tags: objective-c, latex, windows-vista, pygments, texnic-center

I am working with LaTeX on Vista using [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) 2.0 Alpha 3 (build 1118) having installed MiKTeX 2.8. I want to use code highlighting for Objective-C and [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300521/latex-package-to-do-syntax-highlighting-of-code-in-various-languages) that the [minted package](http://code.google.com/p/minted/) is great.
I installed Python 2.7 and [pygmentize](http://pygments.org/) as told in the [minted documentation](http://code.google.com/p/minted/downloads/detail?name=minted.pdf&can=2&q=). I also set the compiler option -shell-escape in TeXnicCenter. The compiler finds the pygmentize script but the following error occurs.

> File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize.exe", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details! LaTeX Error: File `Test.out.pyg' not found. Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: out.pyg) Enter file name: ! Emergency stop.

I cannot figure out how to fix the problem. I tried saving the tex file as ANSI or UTF-8.
The only additions I made to the tex file are the package include

> \usepackage{minted}

and this simple example from the minted documentation.

> \mint{python}|import this|

Comment: This sounds as if the error is directly in the `pygmentize.exe`. Can you try running the application directly from the command line? If this yields a similar error, there’s very likely a bug i Pygments.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds right. When I run the command pygmentize from the Windows cmd in any directory it already states the same error. I guess something is wrong with the pygmentize.cmd script I created.

> @echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize.exe %*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `minted` documentation is outdated: newer versions of Pygments apparently include a Windows executable `pygmentize.exe` (unfortunately, their Trac is currently offline so I can’t look up the relevant revision which changed that).

This means that the fix mentioned in the documentation should be redundant. Therefore, try the following steps:

1. Remove the `pygmentize.cmd` script entirely (best not delete it yet – just rename it). Try if `minted` now works.
2. If that doesn’s work, put the following into the `pygmentize.cmd`:

   ```
   @echo off
   set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
   %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize.exe %*
   ```

   i.e. don’t invoke the `*.exe` file via the Python interpreter.

Unfortunately, I can’t test this now since I don’t have Windows here. But one of the options should work.

Comment: I love it! Konrad, you made my day. It works when I put the pygmentize.cmd file in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin since MiKTex somehow does not realize C:\Python27\Scripts although its included in the PATH variable. Thank you so much.

Comment: Konrad great solution! Im running on Windows 7 64 bit, all you need is to check if the PATH variable for windows has C:\Python27 in it and then use your pygmentize.cmd with the python.exe.